# Android: File Extension Intent Filter does not work properly with GMail/Downloads app

Tags: android, android-intent, backup, mime-types, file-extension

I have an app where I am allowing users to backup data and want them to be able to click on the back up file via a File Manager, GMail, and the Downloads system app.

I have defined the following intent in my manifest file...

```
        <intent-filter
            android:label="Simple Backup File"
            android:priority="999" >

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="ftp"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="ftps"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The above works, if I click on the .sbu file from a file manager, but not from GMail or list of Downloads. I did read that I need a mimeType to get the content scheme working, but when I define a mimeType as either `*/*` or `application/octet-stream`, the functionality even stops working from within a File Manager.

What am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to set any settings when writing the file for the first time? How best would you handle my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by putting content into its own intent-filter group along with a file data scheme, both having a mime-type of application/octet-stream.

```
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="ftp"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="ftps"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />

            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.sbu" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This opens any and all file Gmail attachments.  Not just  sbu, but abc, xyz, etc.  I cannot figure out how to make it filter a Gmail file extension?